# T-SQL: How to insert a repeating set of numbers into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I have a table with an ID 1 - 100.  I want to insert a repeating 1, 2, 3, 4 in ascending order into the second column.  I need to use a variable for the starting number (1, 2, 3 or 4).  I tried using Sequence but it doesn't allow variables.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What are you doing to GUARANTEE that ALL ID's from 1 to 100 will ALWAYS be present?  I ask because the two solutions presented so far rely on that uncertainty.

Comment: @Lukstorms made a correction to their code and now it'll survive gaps in the ID.  Join me in upvoting their entry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [modulus operator %](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql) for that. Modulus operations are zero-based, so there is some adjustment needed to get the result into the one-based regime you need.

If the table is named "SO70806943", the ID column is named "ID", and the column for the numbers 1–4 is named "OneToFour":

```
DECLARE @StartingNumber INT;
SET @StartingNumber = 3; /* For example */

UPDATE SO70806943
SET OneToFour = (ID + @StartingNumber - 2) % 4 + 1
```

Before:

```
ID  OneToFour
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
```

After:

```
ID  OneToFour
1   3
2   4
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   4
7   1
8   2
9   3
10  4
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Updating a CTE with the [modulus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 4 of a calculated row_number.

Defaulting the zero's to 4.

> ```
> declare @start int = 2;
>
> ;with cte as (
>   select col, row_number() over (order by id) as rownum
>   from your_table
> )
> update cte set col = isnull(nullif((rownum+@start-1)%4,0),4);
> ```

> ```
> select top 10 * from your_table order by id;
> ```

| id | col |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |
| 103 | 4 |
| 104 | 1 |
| 105 | 2 |
| 106 | 3 |
| 107 | 4 |
| 108 | 1 |
| 109 | 2 |
| 110 | 3 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7552cfdd4f72d0a7d8bcf97c2affce8a)*

Comment: I read the question as the OP needing a variable starting number such that ID=1 => result of 1, 2, 3, or 4: "I need to use a variable for the starting number (1, 2, 3 or 4)."

Comment: Oh ok, I probably misunderstood that.

Comment: Yeah, I did too at first.

Comment: And, in both cases, the solutions break if there's a gap in the ID.  Expect the unexpected. ;)

Comment: @JeffModen I didn't expect your unexpected comment.  But unexpectedly I agree with it. Updated.

Comment: @LukStorms - You just made my day!  Thank you for the good-natured feedback and the updated solution. :D

Comment: @JeffModen Wonderful, but I'm totally expecting you to upvote now.

Comment: I also have to change my comment in the original post.  Thanks again.